# To set Zoom in/Zoom out for an image inside an Iframe

Tags: php, javascript, css, zooming

[image]How can i set  Zoom in/Zoom out for an image inside an Iframe?

```
   <iframe src="http://localhost:8080/Folder/images/image.jpg?>" 
    style="width:750px;height:580px; " frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

This is my requirement at one side i want to display the image or pdf ,By the other side user want to fill the details of the pdf/image in the text box.

Comment: Why do you use an iframe to show a picture? And it is hard to make just a "zoom". You can change the size with a jquery .css() or .animation()

Comment: Actually In my project either pdf or image  can be viewed in this iframe by user, depends on their requirement,Iam getting zoom option for pdf by default,but for image i couldnt so iam in need of zoom option for image in an iframe.

Comment: So just generate a link instead of an iframe, it will be more easy. For a picture, you can put a lightbox to put it more big

Comment: It can be either pdf or image So I thought its better to use Iframe. Do u think light box suits for both image and pdf?

Comment: The script will suits for both since. Because it is something made for pictures, if you set it to a pdf, it will do nothing special. For example, you just need to set a class and/or a rel to the link. When it is an image use it ! This is very easy ;)

Comment: For your Reference i have added an image this is my requirement ,I think now you can understand why i cant use a fancy box in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Use 
[jQuery Zoom](http://plugins.jquery.com/tag/zoom/) to get what you are looking for.

Comment: Is it possible to Zoom the image with in an iframe by using Jquery zoom?

Comment: Indeed yes. They have shown the demos for that too. Here is one of them. http://www.jacklmoore.com/zoom/ - @Bharathi

Comment: Thanks for your help,but my requirement is if i click once or click + button the zoom percentage of the image should increase.

Comment: You are welcome :) I just found an example with your situation in question. Hope it helps http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/KcGF3/ -@Bharathi

Comment: Thank you You are right but i need this option inside an iframe Is that possible?

Comment: For your Reference i have added an image this is my requirement ,Now Do you have any idea for zoom in inside the Iframe.